# Core-ui styles not considered on Laravel Vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js, core-ui

I tried to integrate coreui admin template on laravel vue js project,
I cloned [core ui vue admin template](https://github.com/coreui/coreui-free-vue-admin-template) and on running serve it work well,
Then i installed all the dependecies of coreui on my laravel vue js project,
On my app.js i already imported coreui:

```
import CoreuiVue from '@coreui/vue'
Vue.use(CoreuiVue)
```

On my component i just test to integrate the side bar. Below the result excepted (this one was from the coreui vue admin template cloned)
[image: sidebar]
My component look like

```
<template>
<div class="c-app">$
    <CSidebar>
        <CSidebarBrand class="d-md-down-none" to="/">
            <CIcon 
                class="c-sidebar-brand-full" 
                name="logo" 
                size="custom-size" 
                :height="35" 
                viewBox="0 0 556 134"
            />
            <CIcon 
                class="c-sidebar-brand-minimized" 
                name="logo" 
                size="custom-size" 
                :height="35" 
                viewBox="0 0 110 134"
            />
        </CSidebarBrand>
        <CRenderFunction flat :content-to-render="$options.nav"/>
    </CSidebar>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import nav from '../component/containers/_nav';
export default {
    nav,
    computed: {
        show () {
            return this.$store.state.sidebarShow 
        },
        minimize () {
            return this.$store.state.sidebarMinimize 
        }
    }
}
```

```
<style lang="scss">
@import '../../../assets/scss/style'; // this the scss style from core ui 
</style>
```

And on my package.json there the dependecies

```
"@coreui/coreui": "^4.0.1",
    "@coreui/icons": "^2.0.1",
    "@coreui/utils": "^1.3.1",
    "@coreui/vue": "^3.2.11",
    "@coreui/vue-chartjs": "^1.0.6",
```

There is the result i got: [image: result]

So on the cloned project on App.vue, i tested to comment the scss import and i got the same result as on my project, it's like if the style.scss is not considered, i've tried to put all the css code (from the app.css compiled) on the style on the component but i got same result.

Answer (score 0):

I've found what the problem,
@coreui/vue provide class with prefix `'c-'` while @coreui/coreui provide class style whithout that prefix, so the style provided by coreui has no effect on coreui vue component. I hope the future coreui user on vue found this to help them.

Answer (score 0):

I've just have had the same problem with CoreUI.
In the end I found that I was using @coreui/coreui": "^4.0.1" just as you, but all the documentation and examples are referenced to the version 3.4 of the library.
Installing this version solved my problem.